# Workflow: Working with git and sandbox on linux

Tags: linux, git, web, kde-plasma, kate

I'am a linux users and web developer.
Actually I'm using KDE as desktop environment and Kate as IDE.

I'm working for a company and we're using remote sandbox for development.
This is my actual workflow:

1. Connect to remote sandbox via sftp using Dolphin (file Manager)
2. Open the file that I want edit and save it
3. Show the changes in the browser
4. When I've finish I must copy the file that I've edited from remote to my git local folder and commit changes.

In the past I've used SublimeText with "upload on save" plugin, but I can't actually with Kate.

Is there a better workflow with Linux and Kate (or similar) editors?
Thanks you

Comment: Sorry, I'm using sftp protocol

Comment: I don't know if you will have enough rights for to it but what I probably try is to mount sftp folder on your system, and use git over this folder, you can pull from another directory when everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with this setup, the fastest way to work will be to have Konsole (or preferred shell application) open with an SSH connection to the sandbox. Git must be installed on the sandbox for this to work.

Alternatively, you can mount to the filesystem and manage the repository directly from your operating system, but I've found this to be unacceptably slow relative to the size of the repository. Moreover, there's something magical about the way Dolphin mounts to remote filesystems using virtual folders that I could never figure out how to navigate to in a shell. I ended up going back to gvfs so that I had a clear path.

Lastly, Kate is not an IDE - it's just an editor. Not knocking it, it's actually my editor of choice in which I spend half of my life looking at, so you've got a friend in me :) Nevertheless, I'm not aware of a git plug-in for it, but depending on personal preference, I'd bet you're never going to beat the git core console app.

Comment: Thanks you mate. The problem of the First method is I have not ssh access to the sandbox... :(. About the second method could be ok but I would not use gvfs... I love Kate becouse it is fast and I love its MySQL plugin. I've seen that kdevelop has git plugin but there is no One for Kate :(